# Finding the probability $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \max\{X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}\})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. real-valued r.v. with continuous cumulative distribution function, and let $E_n = \{X_n > \max\{X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}\}\}$. My reading material then states that

> ...evidently $\mathbb{P}(E_n) = \frac{1}{n}$ (verify as an exercise)

But I don't know how to even begin. Proof by induction is the obvious choice, but I have no idea how to show that $\mathbb{P}(E_2) = \mathbb{P}(\{X_2 > X_1\}) = \frac{1}{2}$ by other than *"since each $X_i$ is i.i.d., then $X_2$ is as likely to be greater than $X_1$ as it is to be less than $X_1$. Thus $\mathbb{P}(E_2) = \frac{1}{2}$."*

I guess that the idea is to divide the sample space $\Omega$ into different "buckets" for each $X_i, i = 1,\dots,n-1$, so that, on average, as each $X_i$ is (~) equidistant away from each other, then $X_n$ has $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of landing to the greatest bucket.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Expanding your "other than ..." thought, for a continuous distribution the probability of ties is $0$, and any of the $n$ i.i.d. samples is equally likely to be largest, essentially an exchangeability and symmetry result

Comment: You do not always need independence  or a continuous distribution, so long as you retain exchangeability and symmetry and the probability of ties being $0$.  For example if you select a sequence of $n$ numbered balls without replacement from an urn containing $1,2,3,\ldots, k$ with $k \ge n$ then you do not have independence but you do have this result

Comment: You are on the right track, when distributions are continuous, the probabilities of ties for independent trials is zero. Then, a symmetry argument yields the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Notice that the events $E_1,\ldots,E_n$,
   $$E_j=\{X_j=\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\}$$
   are mutually exclusive.
2. Their union cover the whole space (with the exception of a set of probability $0$).
3. Since the events are i.i.d., foray function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the distribution of the $$f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$$
   is invariant with respect to permutations, that is, if $\sigma:\{1,\ldots,n\}\rightarrow\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a bijective function, then
   the distribution of $f(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ is the same as that of $f(X_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, X_{\sigma(n)})$. (In terms of Calculus or integration theory, this is a manifestation of Fubini's theorem).

Then, by 1 and 2,
$$1=P[\Omega]=\sum^n_{j=1}P[E_j]$$
By 3, $P[E_j]=P[E_n]$ for all $j=1,\ldots,n$. Hence
$$1=nP[E_n]$$

Comment: Ah, I see. The argument is similar for the minimum, but as the main question has a maximum, you probably should change the $\min$.

Comment: @EpsilonAway: Correct. Notice that $\{X_j=\max)X_1,\ldots,X_n)\}=\{X_j\geq X_1,\ldots,X_j\geq X_n\}$. This are not the sets that you want to work with, but since your random variables have densities with respect to Lebesgue measure, events of the form $\{X_j=X_j\}$ with $j\neq I$ have probability $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$E_n$ is equivalent to the event that $X_n$ is the biggest out of all $X_i$. Now argue that by symmetry and independence, the event that a given $X_i$ is the maximum all have equal probability. Moreover exactly one of these is the maximum.

Comment: ...and therefore the probability of the event $E_n$ reduces to the probability of picking up any of the $X_1,\dots,X_n$ at random? If you'd have to, how could you argue about the probability of $\mathbb{P}(X_i \text{ is the biggest out of } X_1,\dots,X_n)$ for a given $1\leq i \leq n$ in a rigorous way? I know it is a bit counterproductive (even), but my reading material emphasizes such a proof writing style, and I'm not sure how to make the jump from $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}) =  \mathbb{P}(X_i \text{ is the biggest out of } X_1,\dots,X_n)$ to (comment continuous)

Comment: ... the jump to $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}) =  \mathbb{P}(X_i \text{ is the biggest out of } X_1,\dots,X_n) = \frac{1}{n}$